# how to fix this list assignment in mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I want to do the following in Mathematica

```
Table[p[i], {i, -3, 0}] = Flatten[{Table[0, {i, -3, -1}], 1}]
```

But I got an error:

```
Set::write: Tag Table in Table[p[i], {i, -3, 0}] is Protected.
```

However, it is perfectly fine to do:

```
{p[-3], p[-2], p[-1], p[0]} = Flatten[{Table[0, {i, -3, -1}], 1}]
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Force the LHS to evaluate into pieces that can be assigned to:

Evaluate[Table[p[i], {i, -3, 0}]] = Flatten[{Table[0, {i, -3, -1}], 1}]

Comment: I got a lot of warnings when doing so. Is there any clean way of doing this? Thanks!

Comment: @Qiang There are no problems with this answer. I suggest you to try it after a Clear["Global`*"] or a clean Mma start.

Comment: @belisarius: right. I forgot to do clear. But doesn't seem to be very elegant or at least the way I wanted. :(

Comment: @Qiang Perhaps you should be a little more precise in your question. This is a valid Mma way to deal with tables in the LHS

Comment: This only works when symbols have no prior definitions. The following will work also in the latter case: SetAttributes[assignToSymbol, HoldRest];
assignToSymbol[sym_Symbol, lhs_, rhs_] :=
 Set @@ Append[Block[{sym}, Hold[Evaluate[lhs]]], Unevaluated[rhs]] , example of use: assignToSymbol[p, Table[p[i], {i, 3}], {1, 2, 3}], and then  assignToSymbol[p, Table[p[i], {i, 3}], {4, 5, 6}]. One can also make more complex version which will automatically detect which symbols on the l.h.s need Block-ing

Answer (score 4):

The reason it doesn't work is because `Set` has attribute `HoldFirst`. It means that `Set[a,stuff]` passes symbol `a` instead of value of `a` to `Set` function. As to why it has this attribute, ask yourself: when you do `Set[a,stuff]`, do you want to assign `stuff` to symbol `a`, or to the value of `a`?

In your example, `a` holds a table of variable names, so you want the value of `a` and `HoldFirst` is annoying. However, most of the time `a` will have a value like `5` and you want `a=stuff` to assign `stuff` to symbol `a`, not to the value `5`

A common pattern to get around Holding attributes is the following:

```
Set@@{Table[p[i], {i, -3, 0}],Flatten[{Table[0, {i, -3, -1}], 1}]}
```